# Deleting all cells in row after blank space

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I was just wondering if there is a simple way to, for each row, move right and check if there's a blank cell and if so delete everything to the right of it.  Can this be done with a formula?

Comment: You want to loop through your rows, find the first blank cell and then clear everything to the right of it? What code do you have already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the range then use the macro:

```
Sub Delete()   
    Range("A1:A50").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
end sub
```

Where `A1:A50` is the range after the blank cell.

If you are opposed to macros, you can do it manually by:

```
1. Ctrl+G
2. Type the range in. Hit enter.
3. Then just hit the 'Delete' key.
```

Comment: Sorry, does this work if the blank space is in different positions within the row?  E.g. for Row 1 it's in the 4th column but for Row 2 it's in the 9th.  It seems to just delete everything.

Comment: This piece by itself? No it will not. But you can write it into a loop that checks for the first blank cell. After recording the spot of the first blank cell, and then you use `Activesheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count` to find the ending column, then use those as the range parameters.

Comment: That's really the part I'm having trouble with